# Why am I getting a different actual execution plan between my two servers?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017

I have a SQL Server query that runs on both production and development environments. The EXACT same query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    [Record_Transformation_ACCRUALS],
    [Record_Transformation_FA:AMORTIZATION],   
    [Record_Transformation_BONUS:AMORTIZATION],
    [Record_Transformation_CPH:BYLABOUR],
    [Record_Transformation_CPH:BYTARGETHOURS],
    [Record_Transformation_OVERHEAD:CULTURE],
    [Record_Transformation_DEDICATED COSTCENTER],
    [Record_Transformation_PUSHDOWN:EXPENSE],
    [Record_Transformation_OVERHEAD:FACILITIES],
    [Record_Transformation_OVERHEAD:GENOME],
    [Record_Transformation_TAXES:MANAGEMENT],
    [Record_Transformation_TAXES:MARKETING],
    [Record_Transformation_OVERHEAD:OFFICETECH],
    [Record_Transformation_EXPENSE:PASSTHROUGH],
    [Record_Transformation_OVERHEAD:PEOPLEPRACTICES],
    [Record_Transformation_OVERHEAD:RECRUITING],
    [Record_Transformation_TAXES:SALES],
    [Record_Transformation_Static Transfer],
    [Record_Label] 
FROM
    Warehouse_20181204 
WHERE 
    Is_Target_Employee = 1 OR Is_Source_Employee = 1
```

We've compared the create scripts for both of these tables and they are identical (aside from the name of the table in question).

We've also verified they are both using an clustered columnstore index.

On development this query takes less than a second. On prod it takes about one minute. We thought at first maybe the size of the data is the problem, however the difference is minimal (a few hundred thousand rows).

We then checked the actual execution plans for both. On dev the actual execution plan is:

[image: Dev execution plan]

On prod the actual execution plan is very different though:

[image: Prod execution plan]

We find ourselves stumped as to why this is. We have verified that the versions of SQL Server are identical:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU5) (KB4092643) - 14.0.3023.8 (X64)   
Web Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Datacenter 10.0 <X64> (Build 14393:) (Hypervisor)
```

My question is two-fold:

1. How can we identify why the execution plans are so different between prod and dev?
2. How can we get the prod environment to run as fast as dev given a similar dataset?

EDIT:

Some additional requested details:

- Both servers have 8G memory, both running with over 1G free
- Both servers have 2 processors
- hardware is as identical as you get - both the same size aws instances
- We've verified the sql of both tables & clustered columnstore indexes are identical

Hopefully these will help with all the other details for the current SQL plans:

DEV sql plan: https://gist.github.com/klick-barakgall/17a7ce926777a3257f7eecb32859458e

PROD sql plan: https://gist.github.com/klick-barakgall/76eabf1008f5bfb0c51259c2ba3f509d

Adding links to Paste the plan for those interested in digging into the execution.

[DEV](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rkfQew41E)

[PROD](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SkMxlP41N)

Comment: execution plan optimization is a two-fer as well; both art and science. There are so many variables associated between the 2 env. You could have only partial data on dev; # of users using the table; index on those tables; memory bubbles; filegroups on how data is partitioned in prod.

Comment: The first plan is parallel, the second is not. Do your servers have identical hardware, as in, same number of processors?

Comment: What are the *estimated* rows coming out of the filter on both plans? (and for the final result in both?)

Comment: Are the settings regarding the cost threshold for parallelism the same? What are the the Max degree's of parallelism on the server? Are the statistics up to date on both boxes?

Comment: Added details to question for Jeroen. Martin_Smith the details you requested are in the SQL Plans I've linked now. @Zane: just ran "UPDATE STATISTICS [table]" on both servers and then the query with OPTION (recompile) on both.  No change on either performance. Cost for threshold parallelism is the same (5) on both servers. Max degrees are zero (0) on both servers as well..

Comment: Performance tips [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/columnstore-indexes-described?view=sql-server-2014) related? or [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/using-clustered-columnstore-indexes?view=sql-server-2014)  perhaps the delta stores are not getting loaded in prod correctly or the index needs to be rebuilt?

Comment: @xQbert: Thanks for the reference material. I didn't mention this in the question but the table is actually generated first and then we add the ColumnStore index afterwards. After it's been generated, only SELECTs are run against this table. In the course of troubleshooting this issue we have force rebuild the index without effect. Due to this I believe that delta stores are irrelevant (unless I misunderstand them?), and the memory limitations explained in the links seem to refer to the building of the index, not it's use. Do you agree?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Serial vs Parallel isn't really an issue as you only have a max degree of parallelism of 2 anyway.

The thing killing your slow query is insufficient memory grant and massive sort spills (to level 8)

Your query returns `305` rows but SQL Server estimates `2,561,980` in one plan and `3,709,060` in the other.

With 305 rows you want a hash aggregate as that only needs memory for the 305 distinct grouped values, not memory for the whole 6 million plus extra overhead as used by the sort.

Even in the plan with the hash aggregate the over estimate of the number of output rows means you get an excessive memory grant warning.

> The query memory grant detected "ExcessiveGrant", which may impact the
>   reliability. Grant size: Initial 831,800 KB, Final 831,800 KB, Used
>   20,480 KB.

To that end you can try the following to create multicolumn statistics with the aim of getting an accurate estimate of the number of groups so SQL Server chooses a hash group naturally with an appropriately sized memory grant. `FULLSCAN` may not be needed but when I set up a test the default sampling didn't seem to be enough to get the optimiser to use the density info from the new stats with the new cardinality estimator.

```
CREATE STATISTICS SomeName ON  Warehouse_20181204  (
    [Record_Transformation_ACCRUALS],
    [Record_Transformation_FA:AMORTIZATION],   
    [Record_Transformation_BONUS:AMORTIZATION],
    [Record_Transformation_CPH:BYLABOUR],
    [Record_Transformation_CPH:BYTARGETHOURS],
    [Record_Transformation_OVERHEAD:CULTURE],
    [Record_Transformation_DEDICATED COSTCENTER],
    [Record_Transformation_PUSHDOWN:EXPENSE],
    [Record_Transformation_OVERHEAD:FACILITIES],
    [Record_Transformation_OVERHEAD:GENOME],
    [Record_Transformation_TAXES:MANAGEMENT],
    [Record_Transformation_TAXES:MARKETING],
    [Record_Transformation_OVERHEAD:OFFICETECH],
    [Record_Transformation_EXPENSE:PASSTHROUGH],
    [Record_Transformation_OVERHEAD:PEOPLEPRACTICES],
    [Record_Transformation_OVERHEAD:RECRUITING],
    [Record_Transformation_TAXES:SALES],
    [Record_Transformation_Static Transfer],
    [Record_Label] ) WITH FULLSCAN
```

Or you could consider restructuring your database so that the 20 or so columns are in a separate table with the 305 rows (plus any other combinations that exist in the data but are excluded by the WHERE clause) and your original table just has an id referring back to this new table.

You can then rewrite this as a SELECT from the small table where groupid IN (SELECT groupid FROM large table WHERE....)

Comment: @Martin_Smith: Your solution works perfectly. I am curious though if you have any theory as to why the stats are needed on Prod but not Dev? Any thoughts?

Comment: @Martin_Smith: actually I think we might have figured that out. We have just updated dev with a new dataset (there is now over 6M rows, prod was at 6.5M). This dataset now generates the same plan as prod. I guess there was a threshold number of rows combined with poor statistics which gave us a bad query plan. Does this ound about right?

Answer (score 3):

That DISTINCT makes your query shorthand for this:

```
SELECT
    [Record_Transformation_ACCRUALS],
    [Record_Transformation_FA:AMORTIZATION],   
    [Record_Transformation_BONUS:AMORTIZATION],
    [Record_Transformation_CPH:BYLABOUR],
    [Record_Transformation_CPH:BYTARGETHOURS],
    [Record_Transformation_OVERHEAD:CULTURE],
    [Record_Transformation_DEDICATED COSTCENTER],
    [Record_Transformation_PUSHDOWN:EXPENSE],
    [Record_Transformation_OVERHEAD:FACILITIES],
    [Record_Transformation_OVERHEAD:GENOME],
    [Record_Transformation_TAXES:MANAGEMENT],
    [Record_Transformation_TAXES:MARKETING],
    [Record_Transformation_OVERHEAD:OFFICETECH],
    [Record_Transformation_EXPENSE:PASSTHROUGH],
    [Record_Transformation_OVERHEAD:PEOPLEPRACTICES],
    [Record_Transformation_OVERHEAD:RECRUITING],
    [Record_Transformation_TAXES:SALES],
    [Record_Transformation_Static Transfer],
    [Record_Label] 
FROM   Warehouse_20181204 
WHERE  Is_Target_Employee = 1 OR Is_Source_Employee = 1
GROUP BY 
    [Record_Transformation_ACCRUALS],
    [Record_Transformation_FA:AMORTIZATION],   
    [Record_Transformation_BONUS:AMORTIZATION],
    [Record_Transformation_CPH:BYLABOUR],
    [Record_Transformation_CPH:BYTARGETHOURS],
    [Record_Transformation_OVERHEAD:CULTURE],
    [Record_Transformation_DEDICATED COSTCENTER],
    [Record_Transformation_PUSHDOWN:EXPENSE],
    [Record_Transformation_OVERHEAD:FACILITIES],
    [Record_Transformation_OVERHEAD:GENOME],
    [Record_Transformation_TAXES:MANAGEMENT],
    [Record_Transformation_TAXES:MARKETING],
    [Record_Transformation_OVERHEAD:OFFICETECH],
    [Record_Transformation_EXPENSE:PASSTHROUGH],
    [Record_Transformation_OVERHEAD:PEOPLEPRACTICES],
    [Record_Transformation_OVERHEAD:RECRUITING],
    [Record_Transformation_TAXES:SALES],
    [Record_Transformation_Static Transfer],
    [Record_Label]
```

The two most common ways the optimizer tries to satisfy this type of query. First it filters your columnstore index for `Is_Target_Employee = 1 OR Is_Source_Employee = 1`; that's what the filter in your plan is showing. Next, to handle the GROUP BY (or DISTINCT) it will either:

1. Sort the rows then use a `Stream Aggregator` to return a distinct set (as shown in the prod execution plan) 
   **OR**
2. Use a Hash Match to filter the rows and return a distinct set (as shown in the Dev version)

I suspect that the optimizer chose different plans because of dramatically different cardinality estimates. Obviously the Dev plan is performing better. It may be performing better because the Hash match plan is more efficient in this case, ***it is more likely performing much better in Dev because you are getting a parallel execution plan in Dev and a serial plan in Prod.***

The course of action I would suggest is:
Run your query in Prod with the Query Hint -

```
OPTION (QUERYTRACEON 8649);
```

This will force the optimizer to run a parallel plan. If you don't get a parallel plan then you have a different problem (perhaps the MAXDOP settings in Prod are set to 1). If you DO get a parallel plan, and it improves performance, then you have identified the problem (you need a parallel plan). If a parallel plan does not solve the problem then you may want to consider a Nonclustered, filtered columnstore index on that table that includes all the columns in your query and then is filtered with:

```
WHERE Is_Target_Employee = 1 OR Is_Source_Employee = 1
```

You are doing a big scan right now a reading tons of rows you don't need to read.

Post back with any questions.

**UPDATED 12/6/2018:**
Sorry for the late update, a lot of work stuff came up.

I looked into the execution plans a bit more and noticed some interesting things. I took these screenshots before reading what @Martin_Smith posted:

[image]

[image]

I agree 100% that a serial vs parallel execution plan is not the problem here but, in the case of your prod plan, running in serial is making a terrible execution plan even slower. The problem, as Martin explained, is that the hash match plan is a better plan.

Both plans are retrieve a similar number of rows from the columnstore index (5M in Dev, 6M in Prod.) In each plan, all the rows are filtered but, in the Prod plan ***all*** rows are processed *again* by the sort operator vs on 338 rows in the Dev plan with it's hash aggregate.

Regardless of how many CPU's you throw at it: A 19 column sort against 6.3M rows is going to be slow, *especially with a serial plan*. One of the best use of parallelism IMO, is to handle a large sort such as this. That said, a sort should not be required. I have seen this before where, when the optimizer can solve the query using a sort (as in your Prod plan) OR with a Hash (as in your Dev plan) -it will pick the plan with a Hash when you force a parallel execution plan. I suspect forcing a parallel plan, in your case, cause the optimizer to pick the plan that uses a hash.

Lastly - I forgot to mention this before, don't use `OPTION (QUERYTRACEON 8649)` in Prod; it's undocumented. I use it for testing. In prod use [make_parallel by Adam Machanic](http://dataeducation.com/next-level-parallel-plan-forcing-an-alternative-to-8649/)

Comment: Thanks for your response @Alan_Burstein. I'm unfortunately not near a machine that can access the prod environment until tomorrow to try this out, I definitely will in the morning. Do you have any ideas as to why the `cardinality estimates` could be so different when I can guarantee the data sets are nearly identical and the scheme is identical?

Comment: Ok, I needed some time to look at this. First, to read the execution plans you posted I needed to download then them rename them to have .sqlplan extensions. This made it possible to open them in SSMS and look at the plan. I'm looking over the plans now and will update my answer shortly.

Comment: So I gave your query a go, and it actually does run instantly! We feel this may be a good trouble-shooting step but doesn't fully resolve our problem as we want to ensure that generic queries we generate A) run fast, but also B) run similarly between dev and prod. Does this shed any light on why it's so different?

Comment: See my updated post above. To answer your question about queries trying to get queries to run similarly in Prod vs Dev - that's a complex question... Obviously, having everything the same or as similar as possible (server configuration, HW, etc.) You can look into plan guides (I think they could be helpful but I have not worked with them much). All I can say is test, test, test. Consider using the query store and/or Extended Events -- both available in SQL Server 2017. Both tools are helpful for analyzing this kind of thing.